# Mark 14:36, Galatians 4:6 "ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ" what is the exact translation of the phrase?

Tags: romans, mark, galatians

Mark 14:36 "ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ".
Galatians 4:6 "ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ".
Romans 8:15 "ἀββᾶ, ὁ πατήρ".

In Smith Van Dyk Arabic translation it is "يا أبا الآب".

Literal translation of "يا أبا الآب" is: "father of the father"!

So what is the accurate translation of the Greek phrase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translation of "abba" (Αββα, אבא)](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/46/translation-of-abba-%ce%91%ce%b2%ce%b2%ce%b1-%d7%90%d7%91%d7%90)

Comment: @Derübermensch I read the post , it is good, but I am asking about the whole phrase ἀββᾶ, ὁ πατήρ what is the accurate translation. Thank you .

Comment: Add an Arabic tag if que is based on arabic

Answer (score 2):

אַבָּא (ἀββᾶ, *abba*) is Aramaic and is in the emphatic state, not construct.

> [image]
> Alger F. Johns, A SHORT GRAMMAR OF BIBLICAL ARAMAIC, Andrews University Monographs, Vol. 1, p. 9.
> http://www.learnassyrian.com/assyrianlibrary/assyrianbooks/Language/05%20A%20Short%20Grammar%20of%20Biblical%20Aramaic.pdf
> Note: BA = Biblicsl Aramaic; BH = Biblical Hebrew

Thus, ἀββᾶ translates as "the Father." The construct state would translate "father of."
ὁ πατήρ is a Greek translation of ἀββᾶ. This is difficult to translate into Arabic.  It might help to use an Aramaic script for ἀββᾶ.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noted by the OP, the word ἀββᾶ occurs just three times in the NT and always in the phrase ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ, ie, Mark 14:36, Rom 8:15, Gal 4:6.

The word "abba" is a Chaldee/Aramaic word whose definition is given from Thayer in the Appendix below - the vocative form of "Father".  BDAG gives very similar information.

The other two words are ὁ πατήρ which is literally, "The Father", referring to God the Father.  Thus, the full phrase, ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ means "Father (Aramaic) The father (Greek)".  It appears that Aramaic speaking people addressed their prayers to "Abba" while the Greek speaking people addressed their prayers to "The Father".

The writers of the NT simply covered both bases in saying  ἀββᾶ ὁ πατήρ.

**APPENDIX Thayer meaning for ἀββᾶ**

> Ἀββᾶ (WH (βά), Hebrew אָב father, in the Chaldean emphatic state,
> אַבָּא i. e. ὁ πατήρ, a customary title of God in prayer. Whenever it
> occurs in the N. T. (Mark 14:36; Romans 8:15; Galatians 4:6) it has
> the Greek interpretation subjoined to it; this is apparently to be
> explained by the fact that the Chaldee אַבָּא, through frequent use in
> prayer, gradually acquired the nature of a most sacred proper name, to
> which the Greek-speaking Jews added the appellative from their own
> tongue.

Comment: The article can also be used to express something where we would use a possessive pronoun ("my", "our"). It is fairly common in classical Greek, but occurs in the Greek bible as well: John 20:20 is translated with "his" hands and "his" side, where the Greek simply uses the article. In Luke 9:58 "nowhere to lay his head" is expressed by the article τὴν κεφαλὴν. So this could be translated as Abba my (our, depending on the context) father.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement was spoken by Jesus:

> And He was saying, “Abba! Father! [αββα ὁ πατήρ] *All things* are possible *for* You. Remove this cup from Me. But not what I want, but what You *want*.” (Mark 14:36 DLNT)

Those near would have heard three words, *abba ho patēr*, not two *abba patēr*. The significance between the two is *abba patēr* might be mistaken to be a cry to an earthly father, but the article in *abba ho patēr* unmistakably makes this a cry to *the* Father.

The next two are identical to that spoken by Jesus:

> And because you are sons, God sent-forth the Spirit *of* His Son into our hearts crying-out, “Abba! Father! [αββα ὁ πατήρ]” (Galatians 4:6)

> <sup>14</sup> For all who are being led *by the* Spirit *of* God, these are sons *of* God. <sup>15</sup> For you did not receive *a* spirit *of* slavery again leading-to fear, but you received *a* Spirit *of* adoption by Whom we are crying-out “Abba! Father! [αββα ὁ πατήρ]” (Romans 8:15)

With respect to the actual words, *abba ho patēr*, Paul states the believer has the right to make the same call to the Father as did Jesus. This is consistent with how Paul explains his, and believer's relationship with Christ crucified:

> For through *the* Law I died *to the* Law in order that I might live *to* God. I have been crucified-with Christ! (Galatians 2:19)

> knowing this: that our old person was crucified-with *Him* in order that the body *of* sin might be done-away-with, *so that* we no longer are-slaves *to* sin. (Romans 6:6)

For Paul, just as Jesus cried out *abba ho patēr* before His crucifixion, the believer may make the same call since they have been crucified with Christ.

The phrases are identical; the reasons for them differ. Mark's is purely historical: this **what** Jesus actually said. Paul's are ontological: this is **why** a believer may uses Jesus's words. Paul gives two reasons why this is so:

1. It comes from the Spirit of His Son (Galatians)
2. It comes from the Spirit of God and the Spirit of adoption (Romans)

Paul's αββα ὁ πατήρ is empowered by the Spirit of His Son, which is the Spirit of God and the Spirit of adoption.